# Getting the tap position in Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I checked the Google Glass GDK, Mirror API and documentation on gestures.

A tap is detected as KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER

Is there any way to determine the position of the tap on the track pad?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to subclass the Glass GestureDetector and override onMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) to capture the X_AXIS information.  X increases as you tap closer to the front.  1000 is about at the front and 200 is towards the back.

```
package foo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;

public class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {

    public CustomGestureDetector(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(String.format("X: %.2f Y: %.2f", event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X), event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y)));
        return super.onMotionEvent(event);
    }

}
```